# How should I handle front end routing in webpack?

Tags: javascript, nginx, webpack, frontend, web-deployment

I am building a website with separated front end and back end via restful api. When I develop the front end UI, I bought a template that uses webpack to generate the bundled production files.

Currently I am using pure javascript to handle the routing. For example, to show different view for logged in users compare to other users, I did the following:

```
if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token")
    // if token exists and it has not expired, show the logged in homepage. 
    if (token && !jwt_expired(token)) {
        window.location.replace("/index-loggedIn.html")
    } else {
        window.location.replace("/index.html")
    }
```

Here are my questions:

1. I notice `window.location.replace` could be pretty slow and it would take half a second to route from `index.html` to `index-loggedIn.html`. Is this the right way to do it?
2. I am planning to deploy the front end static files on Nginx as a web server. I guess this workflow will be like:
   User sends a request to the "/" route -> Nginx responds with `index.html` -> The above javascript code gets ran -> Another request to "/index-loggedIn.html" gets sent to Nginx -> Nginx responds with index-loggedIn.html

   Is that what actually will happen? It sounds very inefficient to me since I would like to be able to check user's log in status before serving the home page.
3. Is there any other frontend server/framework I can use to make the routing easier? Then I can use Nginx simply as a reverse proxy. I checked out Angular but I think it will take too much effort to convert the whole template into Angular's format. Can I use express just for front end routing?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You are asking too many things with too many assumptions. Let us try to uncover them step by step.

#### Type of Application

Basically, you can build two types of applications: SPA (Single Page Application) or Multiple independent pages application; or the hybrid of two Multi-page SPA application. Typically, we use React/Vue/Angular to build a SPA application.

##### Routing in SPA application

In a SPA application, the routing is completely done on the client-side. The server plays very little role in it. We use HTML History API to achieve this (This is what you are doing by hand using `replace` method).

With this setup, you need a UI Server (typically build with Node.js) or a Nginx like Reverse proxy. Your server won't be aware of the routes that client-side code has defined. The server/reverse-proxy needs to do two things. First, when the request is for asset (request ending with .html, .css, .js, .png, etc.), then it should try to serve that asset. When the request is for non asset (request without any file extension `https://example.com/users/`), then you can **safely** assume that it is a request that must be handled by the client (your client-side code has defined the routing) and thus you must always and always send `index.html` page which then will bootstrap your SPA application.

In the initial boot sequence of the SPA, you would read the `location` and determine if this is a valid route. If this is not a valid route, you can redirect user (client-side only) to some default view or **404** view.

Why you would need to do this? Because initially, your user may just say `https://example.com` and then navigate to `/users` route by some action. But, if user does full page refresh after navigation, you back-end server will see the route as `https://example.com/users`. There you need to handle the fallback route to always serve `index.html`. In this case, **404** must be handled by using client-side code. All the major UI frameworks provide routing solution. You don't need to do it by hand.

##### Authentication

Now if you using using `index-loggedIn.html` for authenticated views and `index.html`, then from SPA perspective, you have a anti-pattern or code-smell at least. You must have a single `index.html` view which takes care of both authenticated and un-authenticated views. In routing world, we typically use guards to protect the views from unauthorized access.

What you are doing would currently work but as you mentioned that you see the lag of half seconds before redirect. And, that would happen on every page refresh. But that exactly is the problem with full client-side SPA apps in general. However with proper architecture, you should be able to address this.

##### Routing in a Multi-page SPA or multiple pages application

If you are building an application like this, then your server needs to be more involved and must handle more routing responsibility. In this case, you should probably use **cookie** instead of **localstorage** for managing your token. Browser automatically sends the cookies to the server and your server then can make the decision if it wants to serve `index.html` or `index-loggedIn.html` page.

##### To answer your question:

> Is this the right way to do it? - It would work but it is an anti-pattern.

> Is that what actually will happen? It sounds very inefficient! - It is not inefficient as long as you are properly loading the views with spinner and doesn't cause awkward UX for the users.

> Can I use express just for front end routing? - It is an invalid question. Literally, you cannot use express for front-end routing. But then if you plan to implement UI server using express, then you can use it to define proper routing architecture eventually making it part of your front-end stack.

In the end, note that there are few more consideration that you need to take into account. What happens when user is doing hard refresh when he is on some route that server doesn't recognize? How to properly support bookmarking capability for your users? Also, are you building SPA or traditional server rendered application? If SPA, use client-side framework. If server rendered, then keep all the logic inside Express or equivalent code. If it is hybrid, determine the architectural boundary.

Finally, if this sounds too complex consider using hash-based routing for your SPA. That simplifies many things at the cost of not-so clean URLs.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer. So basically there are two options for front end, build a SPA or use server side rendering for traditional MPA(multi page applications).  I wanna reuse my current front end html pages so I would like the second option. But the thing is if I use server side rendering, then we are back to frontend and backend embedded together, while my intension is to totally separate them. That's why I build a restful api for the backend in the first place.

Comment: Is SPA a must for separating the front and backend? Is there any way (example) to have a MPA on the front end and restful api on the back?

Comment: @ShawnLi, SPA is the easiest approach when it comes to 100% Client and Server separation. And, if you are going to do that, then better to use some out of box framework as it solves many non-trivial and low-level problems for you. You can do it yourself but that means, you have to assemble everything by yourself. At minimum, you should use some client-side router (there are many) and then run your code with it. There are other ways but they would be more complex and need some sort of UI server as opposed to traditional Nginx or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. front end framework such as React has router that make it pretty easy for SPA. But I can't find any framework that focuses on MPA. All I need is just a frontend framework that I can easily build the routes with static pages.  Do you know any examples? Why they are not popular?

Comment: @ShawnLi There is not dedicated framework for MPA. Just use React/Vue and create Multiple application using Webpack multi-page build. These two would be two different apps.